# Disable/Enable button basedo on Ajax span text value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to JQuery/Ajax. I'm having a problem with enabling/disabling my submit button which I'd like to be based on an echoed span message that says if the inpout the user entered is available or not. I am able to display the span message but the disabling of my button only works in the first instance.

```
PHP
if(isset($_POST['typename'])){
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from ref_posttype WHERE fileDesc = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['typename']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    echo '<span class="text-danger">File Type already used</span>';
}
else{
    echo '<span class="text-success">File Type name is available</span>';
}
```

}

```
AJAX
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#typename').keyup(function(){
     var typename = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
     url:"includes/check_filetype.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{typename:typename},
     dataType:"text",
     success:function(html){
     $('#type_availability').html(html);
     if(html == 'File Type already used'){
        $('#add_type').prop('disabled', true);
     }
     else{
        $('#add_type').removeAttr('disabled', false);
     }
    }
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: because `html` is not only the text but all code so you need `html=='<span class="text-danger">File Type already used</span>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change success function as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"includes/check_filetype.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{typename:typename},
    dataType:"text",
    success: function(html){
        const $result = $(html);
        $('#type_availability').empty().append($result);
        if($result.text() == 'File Type already used'){
            $('#add_type').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else{
            $('#add_type').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally I was able to make it work with your answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome :)) You can check it as answer if that is okay.